# Display Individual with multiple properties using sparql

Tags: sparql, owl, ontology

I have individual that contain properties has_answer and has_choice two time.

```
    <!-- http://www.semanticweb.org/myontology#Which_of_the_following_planet_has_the_average_speed_of_about_30Km/Seconds -->

<owl:NamedIndividual rdf:about="&myontology;Which_of_the_following_planet_has_the_average_speed_of_about_30Km/Seconds">
    <rdf:type rdf:resource="&myontology;Question"/>
    <rdfs:label>Which of the following planet has the average speed of about 30Km/Seconds ?</rdfs:label>
    <myontology:QuestionNumber>1</myontology:QuestionNumber>
    <myontology:has_answer rdf:resource="http://dbpedia.org/resource/Earth"/>
    <myontology:has_choice rdf:resource="http://dbpedia.org/resource/Mars"/>
    <myontology:has_choice rdf:resource="http://dbpedia.org/resource/Moon"/>
    <myontology:has_score rdf:resource="&myontology;4_points"/>
    <myontology:has_Level rdf:resource="&myontology;Expert"/>
</owl:NamedIndividual>
```

What I want to do is to get the property list from the Individual

```
+ "SELECT  distinct   ?Qs   ?CorrAns   ?Choice "
        + "WHERE {?Question rdf:type owl:NamedIndividual."
        + "?Question rdfs:label ?Qs.  "
        + "?Question myontology:has_answer ?CorrAns."
        + "?Question myontology:has_choice ?Choice." 
     //   
        + "}"
      //  + "GROUP BY ?Qs"
       + "";
...
     while (rs.hasNext()) { 
            QuerySolution soln = rs.nextSolution(); 
            String Qs = soln.getLiteral("Qs").getString();
            RDFNode choice = soln.get("Choice");
            String ans = choice.asNode().getLocalName();
            RDFNode Canswer = soln.get("CorrAns");
            String cans = Canswer.asNode().getLocalName();
....
```

that give me result as following :

```
Which of the following planet has the average speed of about 30Km/Seconds ? Choice : Mars CorrectAns: Earth
Which of the following planet has the average speed of about 30Km/Seconds ? Choice : Moon CorrectAns: Earth
```

my question is how can I do to get result in one line as following :

```
Which of the following planet has the average speed of about 30Km/Seconds ? ||  choice 1 : Mars  || choice 2 : Moon  || CorrecAns : Earth
```

is it possible with Sparql to do that ?

Comment: Yes, with SPARQL 1.1 aggregate function `GROUP_CONCAT` while grouping by `?Question`

Comment: I don't see how you'd get the result you're expecting when you're doing `"select ... ?choice" + "WHERE { ..."` which results in a variable named `?choiceWHERE`

Comment: @JoshuaTaylor Thanks for replay, yes it's just here there is no espace it's like this `?choice " + "WHERE  ...` in my code...

Comment: @AKSW is it possible to have two choice in Select for example `SELECT  distinct   ?Qs   ?CorrAns   ?ChoiceOne  ?ChoiceTwo  "... `

Comment: Now I'm puzzled: I thought what you're asking about is to have all choices for one question in a single row by SPARQL? Or what do you mean? Did you try `GROUP_CONCAT` and as I suggested? If you know that there are only two choices, yes you could get both by `SELECT distinct ?Qs ?CorrAns ?ChoiceOne ?ChoiceTwo ...", but you have to use both variables `?ChoiceOne` and `?ChoiceTwo` for the property `myontology:has_choice` + a filter that both are not the same entity, i.e. `FILTER(?ChoiceOne != ?ChoiceTwo)` + a filter to avoid duplicates

Comment: Thanks,   I do like that and I get two line as result  Line1 : `ChoiceOne : Moon ChoiceTwo: Mars` then line2 : `ChoiceOne : Mars ChoiceTwo : Moon`

Comment: Right. That's what I meant with "... + a filter to avoid duplicates". Maybe `FILTER(?ChoiceOne < ?ChoiceTwo))` helps.

Comment: Could you solve the issue? If yes, please provide an answer and accept it. That's how Stackoverflow is supposed to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solve my question by following  @AKSW answers, and fix some issue in my OWL file